# Entity Framework Multi-Tenancy and dynamic schema

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a problem with the Entity Framework and the DBContext with multiple schema names. It only works, if i remove the dbo.__MigrationHistory table or the specific entry.

At First my DatabaseContext:

```
public class AppTenantDatabaseContext : DbContext, IServiceStatusDatabaseContext, IDbModelCacheKeyProvider
{
    public DbSet<Container> Items{ get; set; }

    protected string _prefix;

    public AppTenantDatabaseContext(string prefix, string connectionStringName) : base(connectionStringName)
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        _prefix = prefix;
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<AppTenantDatabaseContext>());
    }

    public AppTenantDatabaseContext(string prefix) : base("AppFramework")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        _prefix = prefix;
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<AppTenantDatabaseContext>());
    }

    public AppTenantDatabaseContext() : this(string.Empty) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(this._prefix);            
        modelBuilder.Entity<Container>().ToTable("Container", schemaName: _prefix);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public string CacheKey
    {
        get { return this._prefix; }
    }
}
```

If i run the DBContext an entry in the table __MigrationHistory is added for the ContextKey of the full class name with the model that contains the schema. If i want to create the tables for another schema, the code runs in a exception, because the models are different. Thats understandable.

Now my Question:
How do i achieve it to work with the migration history table, without deleting it?

In my Opinion it could work if either the __MigrationHistory Table will be created foreach schema name instead of "dbo" or if the __MigrationHistory Table contains an entry foreach schema name combined with the Class name. How can i do this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> How do i achieve it to work with the migration history table, without deleting it?

You may play with `Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);`.

For example `if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_prefix) ) {...}`

This will allow to :

> work with the migration history table, without deleting it

But this will not allow to work with Migration, not for all prefix, except for the default one.

PS: it may be easier to work with a plurality of DBs rather than with a plurality of schemas.

Comment: Is there a way to get this working with migrations available?